# Can Python import search local directories first?

Tags: python

Via the ipython interpreter I am trying to import file `file1` from directory `dir1` like so:
`import dir1.file1`.

`file1` is trying to execute `from types import file2`. That fails on the following error:

```
`cannot import name 'file2' from 'types' (/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/types.py)
```

How can I force the interpreter to favor the local `types` directory over the framework `types.py`?

Edit:
The file directory structure is as follows:

```
./
    - dir1
        - file1.py
    - types
        - file2.py
```

Comment: Show us your file/directory structure. It sounds like you're trying to do things wrong, and you definitely shouldn't try to _force_ the interpreter to do something nonstandard.

Comment: @AKX , I added the directory structure as advised. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need an `__init__.py` in the `types/` directory. However, I _strongly_ advise against naming your package the same name as a library module. Instead, you might want to wrap everything in a package (`myproject`) and then use e.g. `myproject.types`...

Comment: @AKX FWIW, having an `__init__.py` file is not longer required to define a package post Python 3.3. See [PEP-420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) for more details.

Comment: Adding an `__init__.py` under the types directory results with the following exception while trying to open ipython: `ImportError: cannot import name 'GenericAlias' from 'types' (./types/__init__.py)`

Comment: Yep, because now your `types` is overriding the system module. That's why I said it would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import the module from a parent directory not the same directory. So, you can try :

`from .. import types.file2`

or

`from ..types import file2`

Comment: Those result with `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: Trying with .types (one dot) gives the original error.

Comment: @Epic That is a wierd behavior. I suggest you to Rename that `types` folder or include it inside the `dir1` folder.

Comment: I can't change the directory name. It's part of a git project I cloned.